# When pulling a URL from a MYSQL Database, My PHP cURL function won't work

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I am using this function for my cURL queries.

```
function get_source($url){
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$source = curl_exec ($ch);
return $source;
}
```

The function works perfectly, but when I try to run it on a URL from my MySQL database, it wont work...

I have done the following tests...I am trying to get the source of a YouTube video:

Test 1:

```
echo get_source("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxfZkMm3wcg");

**Result: Works, returns the source code of the video.**
```

Test 2:

```
$video="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxfZkMm3wcg";
echo get_source($video);

**Result: Works, returns the source code of the video.**
```

Test 3:

```
$video_arr=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT video FROM videos WHERE id='$video_id'")); 
$video=$video_arr['video'];
echo get_source($video);

**Result: Does not work. A blank string gets returned and there aren't any cURL errors that I can see...**
```

Test 4 (just to show my query is working)

```
$video_arr=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT video FROM videos WHERE id='$video_id'")); 
$video=$video_arr['video'];
var_dump($video);

**Result: string(38) "http://youtube.com/watch?v=WxfZkMm3wcg"**
```

I am not sure what to do or what is even going wrong. ANy suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but should their be a www in your last example

Comment: @fl3x7: It does matter actually. Curl gets a 302 redirect response, which is, in fact, empty.

Comment: Wow, thanks fl3x7, that fixed it. Can't believe I've been working on this for hours and that was the problem xD

Comment: no problem glad it helped. Dont worry, looking at the same code for long periods can do that lol

Comment: Yeah you gotta get a new pair of eyes looking at it to catch the simple things you keep overlooking. Which is why StackOverflow rocks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `true` so the page can redirect if necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I actually fixed it with the www. prefix, but I suppose this would have done it as well since it was trying to redirect me.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `false`?  The non-www url for youtube is trying to redirect to www, but without followlocation, all you get back is a header requesting to redirect.  You either need to follow that manually or turn `followlocation` on.  You may want to use the fopen wrappers instead for simplicity if they are available (`file_get_contents($video)`).